# How to properly read a Point Cloud File in C++ and ROS

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I just started using the `Point Cloud Library` and as a start I would like to read a point cloud from file. I followed the [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/reading_pcd.php) related to that. This is just a small example of a major `CMake` project I am building. Just slightly different from the tutorial I divided the project to make it more `CMake` suitable. The `CMake` runs well and the project seems to be organized. However when I try to run the project I get the following `/home/emanuele/catkin_ws/src/map_ros/src/pointcloud_reader_node.cpp:6:10: fatal error: ../map_ros/include/cloud.h: No such file or directory #include "../map_ros/include/cloud.h"
 error::Cloud::readPCloud(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)` and I don't know how to explain this error.

Below the snippet of code I am using:

**cloud.h**

```
#ifndef CLOUD_H
#define CLOUD_H

#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <string>

class Cloud
{
public:
    void readPCloud(std::string filename);
private:
    std::string path;
};

#endif// CLOUD_H
```

**cloud.cpp**

```
#include "cloud.h"

void Cloud::readPCloud(std::string filename)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    if(pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> (filename, *cloud) == -1) // load point cloud file
    {
        PCL_ERROR("Could not read the file");
        return;
    }
    std::cout<<"Loaded"<<cloud->width * cloud->height
             <<"data points from filename with the following fields: "
             <<std::endl;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < cloud->points.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << "    " << cloud->points[i].x
                  << " "    << cloud->points[i].y
                  << " "    << cloud->points[i].z << std::endl;
}
```

**pointcloud_reader_node.cpp**

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include "../map_ros/include/cloud.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string fstring = "/home/to/Desktop/file.pcd";
    Cloud p;
    p.readPCloud(fstring); // <-- Error Here
    return 0;
}
```

Also for completeness I am adding the `CMake` file below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(map_ros)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    // ....
    )

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
    // ......
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(pointcloud_reader_node src/pointcloud_reader_node.cpp ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(pointcloud_reader_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: @drescherjm, thanks for reading the question. I posted the whole error

Comment: `../map_ros/include/cloud.h` even if it says that is not included, it is included. So I don't know why I am getting the `error::Cloud::readPCloud(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)` error

Comment: I think it means your folder structure is not what was expected from the project.

Comment: From `pointcloud_reader_node.cpp` the folder `..` is `map_ros` not the folder containing `map_ros`

Comment: `#include "../map_ros/include/cloud.h"` probably needs to be `#include "../include/cloud.h"`

Comment: Ok this is weird: I restarted the whole project and now I get a different error: `18:19:18: Starting /home/emanuele/catkin_ws/src/map_ros/src/pointcloud_reader_node.cpp...
18:19:18: Failed to start program. Path or permissions wrong?
18:19:18: /home/emanuele/catkin_ws/src/map_ros/src/pointcloud_reader_node.cpp exited with code -1
18:19:18: The process failed to start. Either the invoked program "/home/emanuele/catkin_ws/src/map_ros/src/pointcloud_reader_node.cpp" is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.`

Comment: in particular I didn't expect this: `The process failed to start. Either the invoked program "/home/emanuele/catkin_ws/src/map_ros/src/pointcloud_reader_node.cpp" is missing, or you may have insufficient permissions to invoke the program.` I never got this error before.

Comment: `"/home/emanuele/catkin_ws/src/map_ros/src/pointcloud_reader_node.cpp"` is a source file not an executable so yes this is very weird. I see you are using `CMake` which I am familiar with, however you appear to be using some script to execute `CMake`.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is not an executable per se, but I am making it executable using `CMake` scripts, in particular: `add_executable(pointcloud_reader_node src/pointcloud_reader_node.cpp ${SRCS})`

Comment: As I understand the error message, the problem is not with PCL, but wich including your own header file into your own source file. The question lacks for description of file's hierarchy used in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem to my question some time ago but wanted to share it in case someone has my same problem. 
So there were two issues coming at the same time that made me think it was a `CMake` problem only:

1) `catkin_make` was not properly compiling not because of `CMake` as I thought for a long time, but because the cache file `catkin_ws.workspace` was causing problem to `CMake` itself. So the first solution to this problem was to erase the cache file `catkin_ws.workspace` and do a fresh compile. All `CMake` issues disappeared.

2) Second problem: The correct pseudo code for reading the `point-cloud` it was like:

```
main()
{
    init node
    create pointcloud publisher
    create rate object with 1 second duration
    load point cloud from file
    while(ros::ok())
    {
        rate.sleep

        publish point cloud message
    }
}
```

And I realized nothing was being published on the input and the   callback was executed.
Below the complete code that reads `point-cloud` from file and gives an output of all  points to a .txt file. I hope this can be helpful to anyone who may encounter this problem:

**test.cpp**

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h>
#include <pcl/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>

void loadFromFile(std::string filename)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    if(pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ> (filename, *cloud) == -1) // load point cloud file
    {
        PCL_ERROR("Could not read the file");
        return;
    }
    std::cout<<"Loaded"<<cloud->width * cloud->height
             <<"data points from /home/to/Desktop/point_cloud/yourFile.pcd with the following fields: "
             <<std::endl;

// Write entire point clouds to a .txt file
        std::ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open ("/home/to/Desktop/exampleCloud.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open()) {
            for(size_t i = 0; i <   cloud->points.size(); ++i)
                   myfile << " " << cloud->points[i].x
                          << " " << cloud->points[i].y
                          << " " << cloud->points[i].z << std::endl;
            myfile.close();
    }
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Initialize ROS
    ros::init (argc, argv, "pcl_tutorial_cloud");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("output", 1000);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
    loadFromFile("/home/to/Desktop/yourFile.pcd");
    int count = 0;
    while(ros::ok())
    {
        sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 pcloud2;
        pub.publish(pcloud2);
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
        count ++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result after running :

1) `catkin_make`

2) `rosrun yourProject test`

[image: pcl_read]